# Keep columns whose column sum is greater than 20th percentile

Tags: r

I have a dataset (df) which looks like:

```
df

X24_TT  X35_FTT X55_FTT X70_FTT X85_TT  X86_FTT X90_FTT X96_FTT
  0       1        0       0      0        1       0      1
  1       0        0       1      1        1       0      1
  1       0        0       0      0        1       0      1
  0       1        0       0      0        0       1      1
  0       0        1       1      0        1       0      0
  1       0        0       0      0        0       0      0
```

I want to keep only those columns whose column sums are greater than 20th percentile i.e.

a) Calculate colsum for each column in "df" i.e an array of colsums

b) Find 20th percentile value of that array of colsums

c) Keep columns whose colsum > 20th percentile value

If we calculate the 20th percentile of colsum of "df" it comes to be 1.

Therefore in a new dataset(nm), only those columns appears whose column sum are greater than 1 i.e.

```
nm

X24_TT  X35_FTT X70_FTT X86_FTT X96_FTT
  0        1       0       1      1
  1        0       1       1      1
  1        0       0       1      1
  0        1       0       0      1
  0        0       1       1      0
  1        0       0       0      0
```

Please note that number of columns are huge therefore provide dynamic solutions

Comment: Your condition is not clear, perhaps you can use `Filter` i.e. `Filter(function(x) sum(x > x0), df)` where x0 is the condition for quantile

Comment: @akrun conditions added

Comment: It is much easier then `v1 <- colSums(df); v2 <- quanitle(v1, 0.2); df[v1>v2]`

Comment: Or with the two typos fixed: `v1 <- colSums(df); v2 <- quantile(v1, 0.2); df[,v1>v2]`